# header is not redirecting and showing blank page sometime

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

In my website, I have a login page. When you click the login button, it redirects you to fbregister.php, which stores user details in a database. After submitting the user details, it needs to redirect the user to index.php, but it doesn't always work.

It sometimes gets stuck on fbregister.php and shows a blank page. I've tried using `header()`. I also tried `echo`ing a `<script></script>` block.

Here is the code for *fbregister.php*:

```
<?php
    include_once('mysqli_connect.php');

    if(isset($_COOKIE['user_email'])) {
        $email=$_COOKIE['user_email'];
        $query="Select * from user where u_email='$email'";
        $res=mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

        $result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        $ures=mysqli_num_rows($res);

        if($ures>0) {
            session_start();
            $session = Array('user_email' => $email);
            $_SESSION=$session;
            header('Location:home.php');
            exit();
            }

        else {
            header('Location:index.php?id=1');
            exit();
            }
        }
    ?>
```

I don't know why it's not redirecting properly, so please let me know if you have a suggestion or solution.

Comment: remove any possible `?>` from 'mysqli_connect.php'

Comment: maybe a not shown error stopping the script before header? switch on error_reporting!

Comment: When you get a blank page, what is the HTTP response code (shown in browser network requests in dev tools)?  If it's `500` then your script crashed.  Does it work sometimes and not others with the code you showed?  Or does the code you show never work?

Comment: @Jeff i did not get you

Comment: @BeetleJuice it does work for sometime but not everytime. earlier i tried with header then after error cam, i try with <script> even then error came then i put exit() even then error come. dont now what to do now

Comment: `Array(...` should be `array(...`

Comment: Your script runs only when `isset($_COOKIE['user_email'])==true`, otherwise is blank.

Comment: @BeetleJuice i dont know how to check http response code. I also check network requests in dev. there is nothing.

Comment: @VirendraSingh If there is no network request, then your script has nothing to do with your the problem because without a network request, you script never gets executed.  As for how to find http response code, search the web for *how to check http response code from browser dev tools* with your browser's name.